# Contact Activity Timeline - adding other Contact related information (Cases created)

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, visual-workflow

A question: would it be possible to add to the Contact Activity timeline items such as Case created , potentially also Chats & Messages from the service console? The idea being a more wholesome timeline for that Contact.

Any other ideas how to achieve this would be good to know.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: It'd most likely involve you creating tasks for those given scenarios so that it would show up in your activity timeline. It'd most likely involve a process builder or code - `when case is created - if contactId != null, create task on contact record`

Comment: That's certainly one idea - and a good one. PB & Flow I can use for that. Thanks.